# Is there any way to record an hls live stream video in safari webview (ionic)?

Tags: html, ios, ionic-framework, video, record

I'm creating a streaming app with ionic. Is there a way to record a video being played on an iOS system? I need to have a REC button working. I have already searched libs and API but I didn't found any, except for experimental WebRTC support. I don't want to ask my clients to turn on experimental features just to get the app working. Thank you. Currently works on Android with MediaRecorder API.

Cordova-replay is problem on iOS 14, because it uses a deprecated API

Comment: what is a HTML5 video? HTML is a text document not even clsoe to a videofile. Whar exactly do you mean with it?

Comment: I have a ionic app, streaming video with <video> tag, and I want to record it, I have already done it with MediaRecorder API but just works on Android.

Answer (score 0):

IOS has an application for screen recording. Just record and then edit the video to remove the edges.

Record screen:

- Android: [ionic-screen-recorder](https://github.com/kwangmeng/ionic-screen-recorder).
- IOS: [cordova-replay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-replay).

Use these two Cordova plugins and you can record the screen.

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't say correctly, I'm developing the app with angular and ionic and I would like to implement the function inside the app... any tips?

Comment: If you just want to save the vídeo, just provide a download button. Or do you want to capture the entire screen?

Comment: thanks I didn't think about that, It would work for .mp4 video url, but there is another case. I have a HLS stream and I need to record that as well. I don't have access to back-end, just the live url, any idea? The tag <video> already works well with that without libs, in the iOS case

Comment: For this, I believe that it is just recording the entire screen. I'm gonna edit my answer and I'll define two links for you to take a look in how to do that.

Comment: cordova-replay has deprecated api's, i have tested it today... I don't know what to do...

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is going through the same problem, use back-end for processing timestamps and solutions to record your hls stream or .mp4 stream and then send it back correctly to ionic app. I haven't found any solution in-app only. Here a lib that could help.

https://github.com/IcaroAugusto/node-hls-downloader#readme